# Find the Möbius transformation that...

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

...maps:

$-1 \mapsto i,$

$\infty \mapsto 1,$

$i \mapsto 1+i$

This is driving me mad!  Should be easy but I keep getting tied up in knots.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the Möbius transformation is that $M(z)=\frac{z+a}{z+b}$, and then by $M(-1)=i,M(i)=1+i$, we can get that $a=2+i,b=2-i$, so the desired Möbius transformation is that 
$$M(z)=\frac{z+2+i}{z+2-i}.$$

Comment: It might be worth saying that the form of $M(z)$ you assume comes from the fact that $M(\infty) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't thought of simplifying the original form by dividing the top and bottom by the coefficient of $z$.  Lesson learned.

Comment: yes, $M(\infity)=1$ is very important!

Answer (score 8):

With $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ we have that
$$
f(\infty)=\frac{a}{c}=1, \qquad
f(-1)=\frac{-a+b}{-c+d}=i, \qquad
f(i)=\frac{ai+b}{ci+d}=1+i.
$$
Thus, we need to solve the three equations with respect to four unknowns, where one of them can be chosen freely.

Answer (score 5):

We can find $\omega(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ using formula $$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}:\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_3-z_2}=\frac{\omega-\omega_1}{\omega-\omega_2}:\frac{\omega_3-\omega_1}{\omega_3-\omega_2}$$ where $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(-1,\infty,i)$ and $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)=(i,1,1+i).$

In our case we have $$\frac{z+1}{1}:\frac{i+1}{1}=\frac{\omega-i}{\omega-1}:\frac{1}{i},$$ where we change $z-z_2$ with $1$ because $z_2=\infty,$ etc.

And now we find that $\omega=\omega(z)=\dfrac{z+2+i}{z+2-i},$ like previous solutions.